# Forms must contain a submit button or an image button

Tags: html, angularjs, accessibility

I have the form below ..

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate>
    <label for="test_element">Test</label>
    <input required id="test_element" type="text" ng-model="ctrl.test"> 

    <button ng-click="ctrl.save(myForm.$valid)">
      Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

I'm using the `Dynamic Assessment Plugin` from here:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dynamic-assessment-plugin/aahpafpbmmgednbflpalchnlbicaeppi

The tool doesn't give a great example of how to fix the error:

```
Submit buttons and image buttons allow users to explicitly request submission of the form and to control the change of context. Forms that are submitted by other mechanisms might change the user's context before they are ready, causing frustration or confusion.
```

What would be the best way?

I dont want to change `<button>` -> `<input type="submit">` since there's `angularjs` code behind the scenes handling the submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="ctrl.save(myForm.$valid)">
  Submit
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have read a little bit about ng-submit, here's the [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit).

I think for that we can make it something like this:

```html
<form ng-submit="ctrl.save()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.test">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I hope that documentation can help you :D

Comment: `ng-submit` is the answer. You get bonus usability improvements too. For example, a user can now press enter while focused in the text input to submit the form. You don't get that with a button click handler.

Comment: yeah and we can add `ng-disable` too for validator

Comment: yeah and we can add `ng-disable` too for validator

Answer (score 0):

**There's no obligation of having one `submit` button inside a form.**

You can view [an example in the documentation stating:](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/sec-forms.html#elementdef-form)

> Finally, to make the form submittable we use the `button` element

with no `input[type=submit]` button.

You can also perfectly have no `button` at all, for instance a `form` consisting only in checkboxes.